# How to repeat iteration based on number of retries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading file chunks to Dropbox and I need to add a simple retry into my loop. So if the first attempt fails, retry another 2 times before giving up.

To give some context. Im uploading a file in chunks to Dropbox. But, I need to allow the script to fail gracefully. Asking the script to repeat the upload 3 times before I kill the upload and give the user an error.

For example (not actual attempt just a concept):

```
    var retries = 3;
    jQuery(dropbox.chunks).each(function(index, chunk){

      var result = anothingFunction();

      if (result == true) {

        //continue the loop

      }

      if (result == false) {

        retries--;

        if (retries > 0) {
            //Retry this iteration
        }

        if (retries = 0) {
            //Kill the entire loop as this upload clearly is not going to happen. 
        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: the if statements should look like `if (result == false) {` or even `if (result === false) {` having only one `=` is a value assignment and not a value comparison

Comment: Is the code block given an example or is it your actual attempt? What is the exact problem? ([Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)) Are you aware that `=` in the *if*-statement is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator?

Comment: `if(result=true)` and `if(result=false)` will both always be true, since you are assigning it to the variable. Instead you want to compare with `if(result == true)`

Comment: Update question to show example as a concept and fixed the == syntax issue.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Is it not working? what is the help you are seeking?

Comment: @Benny I need to loop through the var dropbox.chunks, then if result returns false, I need it to go back through the same index again 3 times. If it always returns false then I need it to kill the loop when retries == 0. The purpose is to run a file upload and if the file upload fails, try another 2 times before giving up.

Comment: Your concept code is ok. What is not working in your real code? Or did you not write the real code, and that's what you need help with?

Comment: @AlexKnopp What I think what Benny is trying to say is that currently you merely ask for a solution but haven't shown any attempt of creating a (semi) working version of your own. The latter is something we can surely help you with and you are encouraged to do so. Otherwise I'd recommend that you get assistance from a JS professional who can help you with building your project. But I would hope that you do try to build it yourself as this is, imo, an interesting case to work on.